# How to solve a Laplace problem using the second shifting theorem if the shifts in the expression are not the same?

Tags: calculus, laplace-transform

Problem:

$$ \mathcal {L} \{(2x+1)U(x-1)\}$$

I was of the understanding that the two shifts must be the same to solve this using the second shifting theorem.

Is it a typo in the question or how does one go about solving this?

I'm not looking for a solution, just some insight into how to go about dealing with the difference in shifts issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write $2x+1$ as a function of $x-1$, which is easy enough to do: $2x+1=2(x-1)+3$.